# Are SIMD and VLIW instructions the same thing?

Tags: x86, cpu-architecture, simd, instruction-set, vliw

What exactly is the difference between SIMD (Single Instruction Multiple Data) and VLIW (Very Long Instruction Word)? Is one a subset of the other? Or are they two completely difference things?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Completely unrelated, and orthogonal.  A machine can have one or both, or neither.  SIMD instructions could be added to a VLIW ISA as an extension.  (But VLIW is baked in to the machine-code format and ISA.)

- [Modern Microprocessors
  A 90-Minute Guide!](https://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/) is *excellent*, and covers both of these concepts.
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_long_instruction_word

**VLIW is multiple instructions in one block to be decoded together, and executed without checking for hazards / dependencies between them**: the compiler is required to do that, so the VLIW idea is to offload some of that work of finding instruction-level parallelism (ILP) to the compiler.
One of the most well-known examples is Intel/HP's Itanium ISA.  https://www.realworldtech.com/mckinley/ covers some details about it, and the first-gen Merced microarchitecture (which wasn't very good).  https://www.realworldtech.com/ev8-mckinley/5/ has more details about the 2nd-gen microarchitecture, McKinley.

VLIW is one way to provide some MIMD capability (multiple instructions on multiple data, doing different things to different data.)

**SIMD is one instruction doing the same thing to multiple elements of data**, so getting more work per clock through the CPU pipeline only involves widening the execution units, not the whole pipeline.  (Single Instruction, Multiple Data.)  A problem with lots of data parallelism can expose that to the CPU in the form of SIMD, ILP, and thread-level parallelism, all at the same time.

(e.g. a matrix multiply or dot product which uses multiple accumulators to create separate dependency chains (ILP), where each accumulator is a vector of 4, 8, or 16 floats (SIMD).  And you can divide that work up across cores, so you can get e.g. 2x 8 FMAs per clock per core on Skylake or Zen2.)